# Including multimedia resources in visual studio c# release

Tags: c#, visual-studio, multimedia

I am trying to compile and "release" a C# .net program in Visual Studio, running it using the debugger or starting the file from the project folder works fine, but if i move the .exe from the project folder I get a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` error.

The problem is that the soundplayer object no longer has access to the file due to it trying to access it using a local filepath.

I am trying to import audio and .gif resources in a way where they would be included in the .exe file and not dependent on having access to the source files in the project folder. None of the tutorials/similar questions I found presented any kind of solution.

Comment: Make them Embedded Resources. You can open them using `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream`. There are plenty of tutorials around on how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Do you know Visual Studio Setup Project? And did you try it? If not, you can check [this link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects) and [this one](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-ai-ext-vs.html), this will permits to chose the folders you want to put your files, and also have a nice installer... Let us know

Comment: I'm not trying to make an installer, just trying to build the program and have it launch with the resources I am trying to include regardless of which folder i put the .exe in. Right now it is reliant on relative filepaths.